# How to exclude specific string from list using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I've use case to generate the list of strings dynamically using **NodeJS**, if the given string is `null` I should exclude that string from the list. **For example:** I've `productID`, `productName`, `productPrice` and `productType`. If `productID` is `null` then `productID` field should be excluded from the list, if `productName` is `null` then `productName` should be exclude and so on. If `productID` and `productName` are `null` then both the field should excluded from the list.

I've sample code below but this is not a efficient way of doing it, can someone please suggest how can we implement this use case in a better way using NodeJS.

```
const test = async () => {

    console.log('generate params')

    var params;

    var productID;
    var productName = "APPLE";
    var productPrice = "12";
    var productType = "Electronics"


    if (productID == null) {
        params = {
            "PRODUCT_NAME": productName,
            "PRODUCT_PRICE": productPrice,
            "PRODUCT_TYPE": productType
        }
    } else if (productName == null) {
        params = {
            "PRODUCT_ID": productID,
            "PRODUCT_PRICE": productPrice,
            "PRODUCT_TYPE": productType
        }
    }
    else if (productPrice == null) {
        params = {
            "PRODUCT_ID": productID,
            "PRODUCT_NAME": productName,
            "PRODUCT_TYPE": productType
        }
    }
    else if (productType == null) {
        params = {
            "PRODUCT_ID": productID,
            "PRODUCT_NAME": productName,
            "PRODUCT_PRICE": productPrice,
        }
    }
    console.log("param value", params)
}

test()
```

**TypeScript**

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ PRODUCT_ID: string[]; PRODUCT_NAME: string; PRODUCT_PRICE: string; PRODUCT_TYPE: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ PRODUCT_ID: string[]; PRODUCT_NAME: string; PRODUCT_PRICE: string; PRODUCT_TYPE:
```

**`product.ts`**

```
export interface ProductInput {
  productID: Array<string>;
  productName: string;
  productPrice: string;
  productType: string;
  shippingDate: Date;
  DeliveryDate: Date;
}

export interface ProductOutput {
  status: string;
}

//Lambda function
export const productDetails = async (event: ProductInput):
  Promise<ProductOutput> => {

  var PRODUCT_ID = event.productID;
  var PRODUCT_NAME = event.productName;
  var PRODUCT_PRICE = event.productPrice;
  var PRODUCT_TYPE = event.productType;

  const collection = { PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_TYPE };

  const parameters = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (collection[curr]) acc[curr] = collection[curr];

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return {
    status: 'success'
  };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a data-structure (object in this case) and add all properties in it

```
const collection = { productID, productName, productPrice, productType };
```

Then you can use reduce to collect it into single object if it is not null

```
const params = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (collection[curr]) acc[curr] = collection[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

**one-liner**

```
const params = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => (collection[curr] ? { ...acc, [curr]: collection[curr] }: acc), {});
```

```js
const test = async () => {
  console.log("generate params");

  var productID;
  var productName = "APPLE";
  var productPrice = "12";
  var productType = "Electronics";

  const collection = { productID, productName, productPrice, productType };

  const params = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (collection[curr]) acc[curr] = collection[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log("param value", params);
};

test();
```

**EDITED**

**one-liner**

```
const params = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => collection[curr] ? [...acc, mapping[curr]]: acc, []);
```

```js
var productID;
var productName = "APPLE";
var productPrice = "12";
var productType = "Electronics";

const collection = { productID, productName, productPrice, productType };
const mapping = {
  produtID: "PRODUCT_ID",
  productName: "PRODUCT_NAME",
  productPrice: "PRODUCT_PRICE",
  productType: "PRODUCT_TYPE",
};
const params = Object.keys(collection).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (collection[curr]) acc.push(mapping[curr]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log("param value", params);
```

Comment: Thank you @decpk. This works! I want to push the not null fields to an array but while pushing I've to use custom mapped fields. For example, if productID is null I want to push productName, productPrice and productType but while pushing to array it should come like this const productArray = ["PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_PRICE", "PRODUCT_TYPE"] productName should map to PRODUCT_NAME, productPrice -> PRODUCT_PRICE and so on. How can we achieve this?

Comment: @DaveBrady code edited. Have a look

Comment: Thank once again @ decpk, I'm trying same in Typescript but getting this error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ PRODUCT_ID: string[]; PRODUCT_NAME: string; PRODUCT_PRICE: string; PRODUCT_TYPE: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ PRODUCT_ID: string[]; PRODUCT_NAME: string; PRODUCT_PRICE: string; PRODUCT_TYPE:

Comment: I've edited my original post which contains typescript program and error details. Can you pls help on this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* if first value is falsy, use the second value */
params = {
"PRODUCT_ID": productName | null,
"PRODUCT_NAME": productName | null,
"PRODUCT_PRICE": productPrice | null,
"PRODUCT_TYPE": productType | null
}

/*
and if you want to remove keys that are null 
( i don't know why you would want to do this) 
import omitBy and isNull from lodash and do the following
*/

return( _.omitBy( params, _.isNull ));
```

forgot that you need to escape underscores in markdown so I had to edit

Comment: Also, since there is no I/O being done in this code, it is not necessary to declare this function as async

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way for **ES6+**

```js
params = {
  "PRODUCT_ID": null,
  "PRODUCT_NAME": 'productName',
  "PRODUCT_PRICE": 'productPrice',
  "PRODUCT_TYPE": 'productType' 
}

console.log(params)

//Removes only null
params = Object.entries(params).reduce((a,[k,v]) => (v === null ? a : (a[k]=v, a)), {})

console.log(params)
```